# How to switch from dedicated graphics to integrated

Tags: intel-graphics

Looks like my main gpu is cooked(display is flickering) so i want to switch to the integrated gpu(i have i7-6700HQ cpu). I have used some commands that i have found but ubuntu keeps telling me "no integrated gpu detected".

Here is the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104BM [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP104BM [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Which discrete GPU are you supposed to have?

Comment: I have gtx 1070.

Comment: btw it is a gaming laptop that i am using

Comment: You need to have the Nvidia drivers installed (and Secure Boot disabled) and then use Nvidia X Server Settings to switch graphics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't work. I cant switch because Nvidia X Server Settings does not have that option at least in my case.

Here is the link of Nvidia X Server Settings that i am getting [link](https://ibb.co/MGJgYvR). In case you are worried about link i uploaded the screenshot on this site https://imgbb.com/

Comment: Btw sorry for the late reply

Comment: The iGPU is probably disabled in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for you help. I think this laptop has disabled iGPU by design or maybe iGPU is damaged or something like this. BIOS does not any options to switch GPU

Comment: No problem @Pilot6

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a desktop computer. They don't usually have swithchable graphics.

If the CPU has an integrated GPU, you can connect your monitor directly to the motherboard. Also you need to make sure that in UEFI settings integrated GPU is enabled and set as primary.